# How can you determine what set of boxes will maximize nesting?

Tags: combinatorics, order-theory

I'm trying to find a dynamic solution to the nesting boxes problem.

You're basically given a set of "boxes" which all have different dimensions. The goal is to find the maximum set of boxes that can be nested inside of each other.

So more formally,

> Given a set $B = \{b_1, b_2, . . . b_n\}$, where each $b_i$ represents a box with a width, height and depth, find the set of boxes that will allow you to nest as many as possible together.

Answer (score 0):

$B$ can be equipped with the structure of a [poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set): we may say that $b_i\leq b_j$ if the box $b_i$ fits inside the box $b_j$. We are looking for the longest chain(s) in such a poset, hence we may recognize the maximal elements, put them in a set $M$, then recognize the minimal elements, put them in a set $m$, then look for the longest path from $m$ to $M$. [Mirsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirsky%27s_theorem) ensures that the length of the longest chain equals the minimum number of antichains providing a partition of $B$.

Comment: Could you by any chance expand on your solution. I was following you for the first half but then you lost me.

Comment: @CrystalPritzker: the longest chain has a maximal element at its "top" and a minimal element at its "bottom", otherwise it wouldn't be the longest. So we may just look at the chains between minimal and maximal elements, in order to detect the longest chain.

Comment: What are you defining as the chains between the min and max? Like I understand that the box with the maximum volume would be the max and the box with the minimum volume would be the min, but how do you know which chain will link them? Or why would they even be in the solution? It's possible that a collection of boxes in between the two of them would have the maximum nesting.

Comment: I never mentioned maximum or minimum elements, but just maximal or minimal with respect to the partial order. Please have a look at the Wikipedia page linked above.